# How to set selected value of jQuery easySelect.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I am using [jQuery Advanced MultiSelect](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/advanced-multiselect-easy.html). I need to preselect means checked one or two values of the list.

```js
$("#modellist").easySelect({
  buttons: true,
  search: true,
  showEachItem: true,
  dropdownMaxHeight: '450px',
})
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/advanced-multiselect-easy/easySelectStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/advanced-multiselect-easy/easySelect.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="model" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Product Model
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="model">
    <select id="modellist" data-max="5" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="one" class="selected">Spinner (4 wheels)</option>
      <option value="two">Duffle with wheels</option>
      <option value="three">Upright (2 wheels)</option>
      <option value="four">Garment Bag</option>
      <option value="five">Laptop Bag with wheels</option>
      <option value="six">Duffle Bag</option>
      <option value="seven">Duffle/Backpack with Wheels</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/Vs-tev/easySelect/blob/master/easySelect/easySelect.js) of that library it appears that it does not have the feature to pre-select items when the page loads. I would strongly suggest you find an alternative library, as frankly that's one of the worst I've seen.

Comment: easyselect doesn't provide a preselect feature. you can use slectize.js useful for tagging, contact lists, country selectors, and so on. here is the [documentation](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Like both of the comments stated, easyselect doesn't provide that feature, but you could preselect the items by triggering a click event.

```js
$("#modellist").easySelect({
  buttons: true,
  search: true,
  showEachItem: true,
  dropdownMaxHeight: '450px',
})

// define the elements to preselect
var preSelect = ["one", "three", "five"];
$('.mulpitply_checkbox_style').each(function(){
  // check if the current item value is in the array
  if($.inArray($(this).val(),preSelect) != -1){
    // trigger a click event in order to preselect the item
    $(this).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/advanced-multiselect-easy/easySelectStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/advanced-multiselect-easy/easySelect.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="model" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Product Model
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="model">
    <select id="modellist" data-max="5" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="one" class="selected">Spinner (4 wheels)</option>
      <option value="two">Duffle with wheels</option>
      <option value="three">Upright (2 wheels)</option>
      <option value="four">Garment Bag</option>
      <option value="five">Laptop Bag with wheels</option>
      <option value="six">Duffle Bag</option>
      <option value="seven">Duffle/Backpack with Wheels</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is taking case sensitive search. How can we remove. Please help me. Thanks in advanced

Comment: I have resolved this. Changed in the easy select js file where value is coming in var val change to lowercase